# Verify via vba to msaccess 2013 that email was sent to Outlook 2013

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-access-2013

I am trying to achieve:

1. the email was sent to Outlook "Sent Items" folder therefore email is
   not in the "Outbox" folder.
2. email did not return due to delivery failure (email will be in the
   "Inbox" folder deliver by postmaster@mail.hotmail.com)

The following code is used to send an email from an Access form via Outlook:

```
Private Sub cmdEmail1_Click()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strBody As String
Dim strPDF As String
Dim strFolder As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strBody = Me.txtSubject
strPDF = Me.txtFile
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Me.txtemail
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = Me.txtBBCemail
    .Subject = Me.txtSubject
    .Body = Me.txtMessage
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
'   .SendUsingAccount =   OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)                         '2nd email
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = Me.txtFromEmail
    .Attachments.Add        strPDF                                                    'attachments
    .Send

End With
Me.txtSent = "email was sent to Outlook "

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot

Norbert

Comment: Could you please clarify what is your question?

Comment: May I suggest [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) instead?  See [MS Access send email](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30905348/138200)

Comment: cmdEmail1 procedure is called from MSAccess the goal is to check if the email is in the "Sent Items Folder" in Outlook without opening Outlook by sending a flag to Access. (I understand that this does not verify the recipient received the email) . The question is: What line of code I need to add in the MSAccess procedure to verify that the email is in the "Sent Items Folder" and not in the "Outbox Folder".

Answer (score 0):

Both of these will be asynchronous and you will be able to process the notification at a later point, seconds or even minutes later.

I don't think #1 will help you much - it only tells you that the network was not disconnected. Why does it matter? Even if it is down, Outlook will send the message later.

For #2, it all depends on who sent the NDR. If it is Exchange, you will be able to figure out the bad recipient address. Otherwise you might just get a message with no good way to figure out what the problematic recipient was.

**EDIT**. For Items.ItemAdd, see the following (off the top of my head):

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim WithEvents SentItems As Outlook.Items

sub SentItems_ItemAdd(Item As Object)
  MsgBox Item.Subject
end sub

Private Sub cmdEmail1_Click()

Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strBody As String
Dim strPDF As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespacee

if (OutApp Is Nothing) Then
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  set ns = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ns.Logon 
  set SentItems = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items    
End If
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

strBody = Me.txtSubject
strPDF = Me.txtFile
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = Me.txtemail
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = Me.txtBBCemail
    .Subject = Me.txtSubject
    .Body = Me.txtMessage
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
'   .SendUsingAccount =   OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)                         '2nd email
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = Me.txtFromEmail
    .Attachments.Add        strPDF                                                    'attachments
    .Send

End With
Me.txtSent = "email was sent to Outlook "

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I am just looking for a verification that the email is in the "Sent Items Folder" and not in the "OutBox Folder" if the recipient does not receive the email we will be advice. Also we can BBC the email back to us to reassure us that the email at least was sent.